# ERROR: 404 Page Not Found in Terminal on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, docker-compose

I am running docker containers on ubuntu.  This issue occurs in the terminal of Ubuntu 15.10.  I start by trying set up nats/elasticsearch/etc. I run 'docker-compose -f docker-compose-deps.yml up -d' from the terminal.  I get an error... ERROR: 404 page not found.  This hasn't happened to me before and I don't know why it is happening.  I tried running 'docker-compose up -d' just to see what would happen. (I knew containers wouldn't build) and I got ERROR: 404 page not found.  None of the code has been changed that I am working on.  Any ideas on why this may be happening?

Comment: I finally found a solution to fixing this issue. Just follow the steps from this url. Don't you love it when you can answer your own questions. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using xenial docker in sources.list, and by changing to trusty version, docker now works ok (on trusty).